# Python - datetime - Check if user input date matches format

Tags: python, error-handling

Imported datetime, I want to validate a user input date to see if it matches the YYYY-MM-DD. If it doesn't, print('Sorry wrong format, try again!') and they get asked to input a date again. If they do put in the right format, function goes on to the next question to user. Right now, my code rejects all date formats (even the correct one). Eventually want the validation function in a separate function so it's cleaner.

```
def add_new_entry(entries):
    
  date = input('When was the transaction? (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
    try:
      transaction_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%D")  
    except ValueError:
      print("Sorry, that is in the incorrect format. Try again!")
      return add_new_entry(date)
    transaction = input('Was it Income or Expense? ')
    amount = input('What was the dollar amout? $')
    note = input('Describe the transaction: ')
```

Comment: Try replacing `"%Y/%m/%D"` with `"%Y/%m/%d"`

Comment: The input prompt message has dashes, but your format string has slashes.

Answer (score 0):

The date format is not correct. It should be `%Y-%m-%d`. [Documentation of the strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
import datetime


def add_new_entry():
    date = input('When was the transaction? (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
    try:
        transaction_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, that is in the incorrect format. Try again!")
        return add_new_entry()
    transaction = input('Was it Income or Expense? ')
    amount = input('What was the dollar amount? $')
    note = input('Describe the transaction: ')
    return date, transaction, amount, note


print(add_new_entry())
```

**Output:**

```
When was the transaction? (YYYY-MM-DD): 2022-01-69
Sorry, that is in the incorrect format. Try again!
When was the transaction? (YYYY-MM-DD): 2022-23-32
Sorry, that is in the incorrect format. Try again!
When was the transaction? (YYYY-MM-DD): 2022-01-08
Was it Income or Expense? Income
What was the dollar amount? $2222
Describe the transaction: Salary
('2022-01-08', 'Income', '2222', 'Salary')
```

**Explanation:**

- When the `except` block is being executed, I have removed the argument `date` as I assume, you want to let the user to reentry the date.

**References:**

- [Documentation of the strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)